# Problems with asynchronous in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to:

1) Make two request

2) Then take data from requests

3) And send response

I am using firebase database. I am taking data from database by `forEach` 
I need to process data and response data(json)

Can anyone help me with asynchronous? Or help write callback function

I read a lot of information about this, but dont understant

My code here works not fine 
I have problems with asynchronous
So how can I improve it?

```
router.get('/places/all', function(req, res, next) {
    var lat = req.param('lat');
        lon = req.param('lon');
        result = [],
        resData = [];

    var query = firebase.database().ref('Places');
    var i = 0;
    var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {          
        query.on("value", function(snapshot) { 
            console.log(snapshot.numChildren())
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                childData = childSnapshot.val();

                var gmapApiKey = 'API_KEY';
                    placeID = childData.placeID;
                    language = req.param('lang');
                    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=' + placeID + '&key=' + gmapApiKey + '&language=' + language;
                    placeLat = childData.lat;
                    placeLon = childData.lon;
                    distanceMatrixApiUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + lat + ',' + lon + '&destinations=' + placeLat + ',' + placeLon + '&key=' + gmapApiKey;

                i++;

                var requestDistance = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    https.get(distanceMatrixApiUrl, res => {
                        res.setEncoding("utf8");
                        let body = "";
                        res.on("data", data => {
                            body += data;
                        });
                        res.on("end", () => {
                            body = JSON.parse(body);
                            resolve(body);
                        });
                    });
                    console.log(requestDistanceApi)
                    requestDistance = Promise.resolve(requestDistanceApi)
                });
                var requestPlaces = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    https.get(url, res => {
                        res.setEncoding("utf8");
                        let body = "";
                        res.on("data", data => {
                            body += data;
                        });
                        res.on("end", () => {
                            i++;
                            result = JSON.parse(body);
                            resolve(result);
                        });
                    });
                    console.log(requestPlaceApi)
                    requestPlaces = Promise.resolve(requestPlacesApi)
                    i++;
                });
                requestDistance.then(function(valueDistance) {
                    requestPlaces.then(function(valuePlace) {
                        resData.push({
                            name: valuePlace.result.name,
                            address: valuePlace.result.vicinity,
                            open_now: valuePlace.result.opening_hours.open_now,
                            weekday_text: valuePlace.result.opening_hours.weekday_text,
                            latitude: valuePlace.result.geometry.location.lat,
                            longitude: valuePlace.result.geometry.location.lng,
                            distance: valueDistance.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text,
                        });

                    }).catch((error) => {
                        assert.isNotOk(error,'Promise Places error');
                        done();
                    }); 
                }).catch((error) => {
                    assert.isNotOk(error,'Promise Distance error');
                    done();
                }); 



            });
        });
    });
    promise1.then(function(value) {

        res.send(value);

    }).catch((error) => {
        assert.isNotOk(error,'Promise error');
        done();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Just a quick comment on the question asking style: you ideally shouldn't be dumping such a large chunk of uncommented code and expect your answerers to take the time to read through it, understand the problem and then offer a specific solution. There are many answerers who will indeed do so, but it isn't fair to them. Please try and update your question by either refining the posted code and keeping it only to relevant sections or adding comments to your code explaining context of certain actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to rewrite this all but rather will give you an outline.

First of all the firebase SDK has promises available in lieu of using callbacks. Use those instead of adding new Promise to wrap them. This will help streamline the code structure and enable making the whole promise chain simpler

I'm not sure which package `htts.get()` comes from but it too likely has promises. Convert to using those also

The other trick will be to combine the 2 nested requests into one promise which can be done using Promise.all()

So here's the basic code outline. Note that I have not paid a lot of attention to exactly how you want all this data processed in order to send to client. You will need to adjust as needed

You probably want to break this whole code block down into smaller functions also to make the logic easier to follow

Also note I have not added any error handling `catch()`s which is going to be up to you

```
// use firebase promise instead of callback
var mainpromise = query.on("value").then(function(snapshot) {

  var subPromises = [];


  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    //childData = ...

    // look into https promises instead of wrapping in `new Promise
    var placesPromise new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      https.get(distanceMatrixApiUrl, res => {
        // .....
        res.on("end", () => {
          body = JSON.parse(body);
          resolve(body);
        });
      });
    });

    var distancePromise = new Promise.... // similar to above

    // combine these promises into one
    var combinedPromise = Promise.all([placesPromise, distancePromise]).then(function(resultsArray) {
      var places = resultsArray[0],
        distances = resultsArray[1];
      //assign above to childData or whatever you want to do with them
      return childData;// or return processed results or skip this `then and do all processing in the next then() commented below

    })
    // store combined promises in array
    subPromises.push(combinedPromise);

  });

  // return promise to resolve mainPromise
  return Promise.all(subPromises)// might need a `then()` here to return processed data depending on structure you want returned

});

mainPromise.then(function(results) {
  // process and send results which is array of all the childData from snapshot.forEach 

    res.send(processedData);

})
```